# Flight reservation for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, tickets, eu

One of the necessary documents for a Schengen visa for non EU citizens is proof of your flights, but it doesn't state the actual (e-)tickets (for which I already paid), or the reservation of flights.

So my question is, which option would be more acceptable (if I can provide any of them) to provide printed tickets to an EU member embassy or reservation of flights (reservation does not expect payment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from [ANNEX II of Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810):

> 3. for journeys undertaken for the purposes of tourism or for private reasons:
>
> ...
>
> (b) documents relating to the itinerary:
>
> — confirmation of the booking of an organised trip **or any other
>   appropriate document indicating the envisaged travel plans**,
>
> — in the case of transit: visa or other entry permit for the third
>   country of destination; tickets for onward journey;

So the actual e-ticket is not required, and booking confirmation should be enough - as long as it indicates your travel plans. However if you already have an issued e-tickets which state your itinerary, they can serve as such indeed.

Comment: Is it possible to get this booking confirmation without actually paying for the flight? because the visa can be denied, in which case, most of the the money paid would be wasted.