# Can Polish embassy refuse visa if flight itinerary not verified?

Tags: air-travel, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, embassies

I have appointment at embassy in few days. I got flight itinerary a week ago. Today, without any reason, I tried to verify my itinerary online but the airline showed that this itinerary has expired.

After doing some research, I came to know that flight itineraries expire after 3 to 4 days. I am expecting my visa 15 days after I submit my documents including flight itinerary.

My question is, If I show a flight itinerary which expires before embassy verifies it, can embassy refuse my visa for this reason?

Comment: Your visa can be refused pretty much with no reason, "just because they don't like you". So, yes of course they can refuse because can't confirm something. The real question is what's the probability of such a scenario. And the answer is "low".

Comment: Itinerary has little meaning. If you want to work or to illegal immigrate, you will do also with a legitimate itinerary. Just you should have an idea of where you want to go (and how and costs), else it would really seem you have a fake itinerary.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/flight-reservation-for-schengen-visa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I got my visa 15 days after submitting the documents. My flight itinerary was legit but it expired 3 days after I booked (before submitting the documents to the embassy).

Embassy issued the visa so if your all the documents are original but flight itinerary is expired, you can get the visa as the embassy also knows that no one is going to buy a full ticket before their visa.

Hope this will help others.